# Can I creat a View output using the root path?

Tags: views

just need a simple task. I need to change the homepage based on a view.

If I edit the path inside view settings something like /home it works. But if I try to use the default site root path it displays:

```
Display "Page" uses a path but the path is undefined.
```

That means I am forced to set up my site homepage to www.domain.com/home

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

Your view will need a path set, in this case 'home' and then within your site's **Site Information** settings just set 'home' as the *Default front page* (for Drupal 7 got to http://www.yoursite.com/admin/config/system/site-information).

When you access the URL of your site you will see your View, setting the homepage menu link to '' will also direct users to your homepage without adding '/home' to the URL.